# XML error in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml

Following is the query that I am executing. I am getting XML input from c# in @XMLdata parameter.

```
CREATE  TABLE  #TablesList
(
    TableName VARCHAR(500),
    RefTable VARCHAR(500),
    RefTableIDColumn VARCHAR(500)
)


SET @Query = @Query + ' INSERT INTO #TablesList SELECT ref.value(''tablename[1]'',''nvarchar(500)'') AS tablename,'
SET @Query = @Query + ' ref.value(''refTable[1]'',''nvarchar(500)'') AS refTable, ref.value(''refTableIDColumn[1]'',''nvarchar(500)'') AS refTableIDColumn FROM '
SET @Query = @Query + @XMLdata+'.nodes(''//Table[@name="'+@DataItem+'"]'') AS R(ref)'
EXEC(@Query)
```

When I execute the query, I get the following error. Error is for the 2nd last line

```
The data types varchar(max) and xml are incompatible in the add operator.
```

Comment: What are the data types of `@Query` and `@XMLdata`?

Comment: varchar(max) and XML respectively

Comment: Then it won't work because you try to convert an `XML` data type implicitly into a `varchar` which isn't defined. If you need to access the `XML` as an `XML` data type in the constructed query, you need to pass it, select it or otherwise construct it within the query you're trying to create.

Comment: Please explain, how you call this. From your last question I take, that you have a bigger XML where you pick one node with its children and then you pass this to SQL. Just wirte `SELECT @Query` instead of `EXEC(@Query)` and you will see, that the query is not the way you expect it to be... So once again: Please tell us how you call this from C# and how you handle this in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of injecting content of `@XMLdata` into your dynamic SQL string, try to pass `@XMLdata` as parameter to `sp_executesql`  :

```
.....
SET @Query = @Query + '@XMLdata.nodes(''//Table[@name="'+@DataItem+'"]'') AS R(ref)'
EXEC sp_executesql @Query, N'@XMLdata XML', @XMLdata
```

As far as dynamic SQL posted in the question is concerned, you can avoid using dynamic SQL completely. The only 'dynamic' part of the dynamic SQL comes from value of `@DataItem` variable, which can be handled casually using [`sql:variable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254.aspx), as follow :

```
INSERT INTO #TablesList 
SELECT 
    ref.value('tablename[1]','nvarchar(500)') AS tablename,
    ref.value('refTable[1]','nvarchar(500)') AS refTable, 
    ref.value('refTableIDColumn[1]','nvarchar(500)') AS refTableIDColumn 
FROM @XMLdata.nodes('//Table[@name=sql:variable("@DataItem")]') AS R(ref)
```

Comment: I think, you magic glass bulb points in the right direction (+1 from my side), but my question was, why there's need of dynamic SQL and `sp_executesql` at all?

Comment: @Shnugo You're right. The SQL that OP posted can be done without dynamic SQL at all (updated my answer to include this point). Maybe there is portion of the dynamic SQL that isn't show in question which forced *him* to go that route, not sure....